# How do I specify only certain integers as oppossed to looping through a whole range in lua?

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua

Simple question, but I don't have the time to dig to find the answer.

Using lua:

I can loop through ranges. e.g. for i = 1,7 do...

but I want only to loop for certain quantities- say 1, 4 and 7.

What is the syntax for doing this in lua?

Thanks!

Comment: `for i = 1, 7, 3 do ... end`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific set of integers, you can always loop over an array containing those integers:

```
for _, i in ipairs{1, 4, 7} do
end
```